# multiple field validation using F# (inside an azure function)

Tags: f#, azure-functions

I have an azure function based on the http post template.  I expanded the json from 1 prop to 3.

```
let versionJ = json.["version"]
let customerIdJ = json.["customerId"]
let stationIdJ = json.["stationId"]
match isNull versionJ with
```

What is the best way to check for null across all three?  Use a tulple?

```
match isNull versionJ, isNull customerIdJ, isNull stationIdJ with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to check for exactly.
If you want to see that there is at least 1 null, then you can do the following:

```
let allAreNotNull = [versionJ; customerIdJ; stationIdJ] 
                    |> List.map (not << isNull)
                    |> List.fold (&&) true
```

If you want to check that all of them are nulls you can do the following:

```
let allAreNull = [versionJ; customerIdJ; stationIdJ]
                 |> List.map isNull
                 |> List.fold (&&) true
```

**update**

You can also replace it with `List.forall`:

```
[versionJ; customerIdJ; stationIdJ]
|> List.forall (not << isNull)


[versionJ; customerIdJ; stationIdJ]
|> List.forall isNull
```

Comment: When you want to use List(which lead do use more resources than simple if). There are simpler solutions:

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think using simple if would be cleaners solution,
if you have defined `isNull` as:

```
let inline isNull value = (value = null)
```

then just do:

```fs
if isNull versionJ && isNull customerIdJ && isNull stationIdJ then
    // your code
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is being inspired by Applicatives that apply `createRecord` if all elements `(<>) null`.

```
let createRecord v c s  = v, c, s

let inline ap v f =
  match f, v with
  | _     , null
  | None  , _     -> None
  | Some f, v     -> f v |> Some

let v =
  Some createRecord 
  |> ap json.["version"]
  |> ap json.["customerId"]
  |> ap json.["stationId"]
```